# "System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<..> does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor'" even though namespace is included in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

After updating my build via an SVN repo, all of a sudden all my view code is broken because my Views can't seem to resolve the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace. I keep getting the above message with reference to Html methods (e.g. `Html.DisplayFor`, `Html.RadioButton`, etc.in Mvc views. However, the namespace is clearly included in the Web.config

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Any other ideas as to why this might not work?

Comment: Have you checked that `System.Web.Mvc` is still referenced in your project?

Comment: I have run into this issue before, make sure if you have more than one config file that it is located in all of them. I once had an update change some configs around and not re-add the mvc decleration.

Comment: @Nomad101 I think this is the issue... Someone removed on of the Web.config files from the project, but not View/Web.config

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but I would check the reference path for System.Web.Mvc.  Perhaps you are referencing some version of the System.Web.Mvc library that no longer exists in the directory location on your machine since u pulled down a fresh copy of the repo.